# Can I replace NULL values which are returned from calculated with text in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a calculated field which sometimes returns NULL. I want to replace those instances with  text "Data not found" 
I did try using IFNULL function but Im not able to add text, it accepts only 0.

Comment: Can you provide the formula of the calculated field and how you try to use IFNULL in it? That would help troubleshooting

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply I found a solution to my problem. I used IFNULL(STR(<field>, "Data")